# Share intent for image from sd card not showing option to share on Facebook, Google+ or any social networking site

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I used a simple share intent to share images stored on the sd card. It currently shows me option to share on my email and google drive. But no option to share on facebook, twitter or any other social network site.

Below is the code which I use for share intent:

```
        // Populate the share intent with data
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
          + File.separator + folderName + File.separator +mImageTitles.get(position)));

        // Setting up the share intent
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("img/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mImageTitles.get(position));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
shareIntent.setType("img/*");
```

to

```
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a facebook account to the android device and check.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason adding an entry to Mediastore aka Gallery during image save, helps in getting the share function for all social networks to be working.

If anyone can get me the reason for this behavior it would be great..

Answer (score 0):

Is it the type? try `shareIntent.setType("image/*");`

or use the MediaStore

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
        context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "title",
        "description");

// will be null if we don't have permissions to write external
if (path != null) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
}
```